# Deleting list from a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, type-conversion, conditional-statements

I need to delete these lists inside of list that contains the `/` symbol.

List for example:

```py
X = [['a/','$1'], ["c","d"]]
```

so `X[0]` should be deleted. The actual list are much longer and contains more instances of this condition.

I tried use something like:

```py
print([l for l in X if l.count("/") <1])
```

But if I understand correctly because the `/` is attached to another symbol he is not counted.

Should I convert this list of lists to string, separate the `/` from another character, and then use the count function, or there is better solution?

Answer (score 5):

One way to search `"/"` in each item in the sublists is to wrap a generator expression with `any`. Since you don't want sublists with `"/"` in it, the condition should be `not any()`:

```py
out = [lst for lst in X if not any('/' in x for x in lst)]
```

Output:

```py
[['c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to filter() applies that lambda function to every list in X and filters out list with '/'.

```
result = list(filter(lambda l: not any('/' in s for s in l), X))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
while counter < len(X):
    removed = False
    for i in X[counter]:
        if '/' in i:
            X.pop(counter)
            removed = True
            break
    if not removed:
        counter += 1
```

Comment: this will not work. Try it with `[['/'],['/'], ['/']]`

Comment: Hi! Thanks. Can you explain how/where you propose to use `[['/'],['/'], ['/']]` ?

Comment: The code works now. "counter" keeps track of the current index in the list, and it is increased only if an element is removed in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
X = [['a/','$1'], ["c","d"]]
```

You can convert the sub lists to their `repr` string representations and detect the `/` in that string:

```
new_x=[sl for sl in X if not '/' in repr(sl)]
```

Or, you can use `next`:

```
new_x=[sl for sl in X if not next('/' in s for s in sl)]
```

Either:

```
>>> new_x
[['c', 'd']]
```